# FreeBSD : Unable to start apache

Tags: apache, freebsd

I installed the apache24 via pkg installer

```
pkg install apache24
```

and added the following line
`apache24_enable="YES"` to the `/etc/rc.conf` file

now I am trying to start the apache with `service apache24 start`

and it displays the following error

```
apache24 does not exist in /etc/rc.d or the local startup directories(/usr/local/etc/rc.d)
```

How can I start `apache`

Comment: You can run `service -l` to see which services are *installed*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If apache24 has been correctly installed, the startup script will be in the /usr/local/etc/rc.d/ directory. First check this directory to ensure that a file called apache24 exists:

```
ls /usr/local/etc/rc.d/
```

To list all of the installed packages, use:

```
pkg info
```

Comment: I tried reinstalling the apache24 and it is working now.thanks